# Get data from a compound query in firestore with cloud function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

First I search a specific document with a document. In this function I use different filters for getting specific values from the data. The result of this filters is an array that will use it form a "foreach". The result is concatenated in `elementosaux` and next is equal to `elementos`. The problem is that i print o get the value `elementos` the result is `undefined`

This is the code. Thanks for your help.

```js
exports.autentifyday = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
        var db = admin.firestore();
        const key=req.query.key;
        const dia=req.query.dia;
         db.collection("/servicios_disponibles/").doc(key).get().then(function(doc){
            var Ddr;
            var Str;
            var horario;
            var horas;
            var horasaux;
            var horasselected;
            var elementos: any[] = [];
            var elementosaux: any[] = [];
            var elementoselement;
            if( doc.exists){
                var diaselected;
                Ddr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc.data()));
                horario=Ddr.horario;
                horario.filter((dias: { dia: any; disponibilidad: boolean; })=>{
                    if(dias.dia==dia){
                        if(dias.disponibilidad==true){
                            diaselected=dias; 
                        }
                    }
                });
                horas=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(diaselected));
                horasaux=horas.horas;
                horasselected=horasaux.filter((hora: { disponibilidad: boolean; })=>hora.disponibilidad==true);
                horasselected.forEach(function(hora: { hora: any; }){
                    db.collection("pedidos_servicios").where("key","==",key)
                    .where("horas","array-contains",hora.hora).get().then(snapshot=>{
                        snapshot.forEach(doc3=>{
                           elementoselement = {
                                "horas": doc3.data().horas
                            }
                            elementosaux = elementosaux.concat(elementoselement);
                            console.log(elementosaux)//return an array with the answer query
                        });
                        elementos=[];
                        elementos=elementosaux;
                        console.log(elementos)//is undefined in this point
                    }).catch((e)=>console.log(e))            
                })
                }
            console.log(elementosaux)//is undefined in this point
            res.send(Str);
            return Str;
         }).catch(reason => {
            res.send(reason);
            console.log(reason);
            return reason;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you checked were if you get anything in `snapshot`? How do you print this `elementos` value?

Comment: the problem is that inside the foreach when I print the value it works, but when I print it outside the foreach it appears in undefined, how can I get it to print the value when the foreach finishes executing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be metter of asynchronous code. I took part of your code and created simple example:

```
const db = new Firestore()

var elementos: any[] = [];
var elementosaux: any[] = [];
var elementoselement;

let colRef = db.collection("collection1");

if (true) {
    console.log("start")
    colRef.get().then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc3=>{
            elementoselement = {
            "horas": doc3.data().horas
            }
            console.log("elementoselement",elementoselement)
            elementosaux = elementosaux.concat(elementoselement);
            console.log("elementosaux inside snapshot", elementosaux)//return an array with the answer query
        });
        elementos=[];
        elementos=elementosaux;
        console.log("elementos inside snapshot", elementos)//is undefined in this point
        });
    console.log("elementosaux outside snapshot", elementosaux)
    console.log("elementos outside snapshot", elementos)
}
console.log("elementosaux outside if", elementosaux)//is undefined in this point
console.log("end")
```

I added to my firestore collection `collection1` with one document containing field `horas: horas_value` - to make it working.

The example contains more log information about which part of code particular log is. When you run it like `ts-node test_main.ts` you get following result:

```
start
elementosaux outside snapshot []
elementos outside snapshot []
elementosaux outside if []
end
elementoselement { horas: 'horas_value' }
elementosaux inside snapshot [ { horas: 'horas_value' } ]
elementos inside snapshot [ { horas: 'horas_value' } ]
```

As `get` is asynchronous you can see that logs inside it are at the end. 
There is a lot of possibilities to deal with that. For example you can put whole `if` in 'async' function and add 'await' to get:

```
async function main()  {
    if (true) {
        ....
        await colRef.get().then((snapshot) => {
        ....
}
main()
```

and then result is:

```
start
elementoselement { horas: 'horas_value' }
elementosaux inside snapshot [ { horas: 'horas_value' } ]
elementos inside snapshot [ { horas: 'horas_value' } ]
elementosaux outside snapshot [ { horas: 'horas_value' } ]
elementos outside snapshot [ { horas: 'horas_value' } ]
elementosaux outside if [ { horas: 'horas_value' } ]
end
```

Only I don't know why you say this is `undefined`, it shouldn't be...
I have empty arrays... Maybe it's a matter of way how to run the code.

I hope it will help!

Comment: The problem is that i created de foreach to search multiple times, in the final i intent concat the all results

Comment: it should be possible using async/await. This is quite common problem you can google how to use async function in sync code. For example I found something that may help you https://medium.com/@patarkf/synchronize-your-asynchronous-code-using-javascripts-async-await-5f3fa5b1366d...